# Using Array Values in Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a query to select a limited result based on a set parameter:

```
$query = $this->db->query ("
    SELECT 
        p.product_id, 
        p.quantity 
    FROM {$this->prefix}product p 
    LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}product_to_category pc 
        ON (p.product_id = pc.product_id) 
    WHERE pc.category_id = '3' 
    AND p.status = '1' 
    ORDER BY p.quantity DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 4");
```

This returns the 4 products with the highest quantity in stock where the product's `category_id` = 3.

I'd like to have this use an array of category id's as opposed to a static one. ie:

`$categories = array(2, 6, 22, 33, 34, 83, 220, 222, 886, 897);`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert the array to a string and use that in your query. Please note that the below assumes that $categories are already safe and wont contain malicious input. If this is not the case you'll need to clean the input.

```
$categoriesClause = implode(",",$categories);

$query = $this->db->query ("
    SELECT 
        p.product_id, 
        p.quantity 
    FROM {$this->prefix}product p 
    LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}product_to_category pc 
        ON (p.product_id = pc.product_id) 
    WHERE pc.category_id IN ($categoriesClause)
    AND p.status = '1' 
    ORDER BY p.quantity DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 4");
```

Comment: This also assumes the array values are already quoted, unfortunately. You'll need to add an `array_walk` before imploding to cover that.

Comment: @Anthony The askers example was a list of ints. If it was an array of strings you could use `$categoriesClause = "'" . implode("','",$categories) . "'";`

Comment: (assuming it's non empty)

Comment: the OP also wraps the category_id in single quotes in his example query and imploding with the quote marks is always a nightmare in my experience. Check out my answer!

Comment: Works perfect. Is there a way to return ONLY one product per each category, ie: the greatest quantity of each category? Right now the query is sorting only by quantity so I'm getting multiple products from the same category since they have greater quantities than products from a different category.

Comment: @VinceKronlein - that's a bit tricker. I think a group by might work, but maybe not. What if out of the 5 categories only 2 categories matches, would you want 2 products from the two matching categories (to make 4 total in result) or just 2 products?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `What if out of the 5 categories only 2 categories matches` all the categories have products and quantities. As I said under your answer, the categories aren't passed in dynamically, they are hard set. All will return something.

Comment: I will start a new question for this using the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IN` clause.

```
WHERE pc.category_id in (2, 6, 22, 33, 34, 83, 220, 222, 886, 897);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your categories are text instead of numeric, they will need to be quoted first before they can go into the query.

You can use `array_walk` to do this and an anonymous callback function on PHP 5.3 and later. You can also go ahead and escape the values to make them safe while your looping through them:

```
$categories = array(2, 6, 22, 33, 34, 83, 220, 222, 886, 897);

array_walk($categories, function( &$category ) { 
     $category = $this->db->escape_string($category);
     $category = "'{$category}'";
 });

$categories_inclause = implode(",", $categories);

$this->db->query = "SELECT blah WHERE pc.category_id IN ($categories_inclause)";
```

Comment: They are statically set numerically so this isn't an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `IN()` in combination with `implode()`:

```
$query = $this->db->query ("
SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    p.quantity 
FROM {$this->prefix}product p 
LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}product_to_category pc 
    ON (p.product_id = pc.product_id) 
WHERE pc.category_id = IN(" . implode(',', $categories) . ") 
AND p.status = '1' 
ORDER BY p.quantity DESC 
LIMIT 0, 4");
```